# PowerShell parse git string

Tags: git, powershell

We have a PowerShell script to parse date strings returned from git. This no longer works:

```
$lastUpdateString = git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d %T" --format="%ad"
```

We now get this error when running the script: git : fatal: invalid strftime format: '%Y/%m/%d %T'

I guess git changed their date format? This is what the "raw" date looks like: Mon May 17 15:53:59 2021 -0400

Anywho, I've tried a bunch of different things like ParseExact (I first stripped off the day of the week and the timezone or whatever -0400 is).

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact($lastUpdateString, "MMM dd hh:mi:ss yyyy", [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::InvariantInfo, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
```

throws a "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." exception.

I'm getting kind of tired searching the internet for a valid solution. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: This error is from `compat/mingw.c` (MinGW). The command `git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d %T" --format="%ad"` works for me in Bash on Linux. (Maybe I’m just telling you things you already know.)

Comment: [Looks like `%T` is the problem](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/793/)

Comment: As I am looking at this closer, I think it might be that now git returns hours in military mode (15 => 3PM) and powershell doesn't like military time.

Comment: The error is coming from git(1). I am not a user of PowerShell but I don’t think it’s relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a little function to convert the git date to one PowerShell understands. Not sure why I was worried about hours and am/pm stuff anyway. I just want to delete branches that are over a year old and who cares what time they were made. Just want the date.

Here is the function in case anyone cares.

It basically turns this: Thu Dec 9 08:52:15 2021 -0500

into this: 12/9/2021

```
function ConvertGitDate {
    param (
        [string]$gitDate,
        [string]$psDate
    )
    $psMonth = 0
    $dateparts = $gitDate -split " "
    switch ($dateparts[1]) {
        "Jan" {
            $psMonth = 1
        }
        "Feb" {
            $psMonth = 2
        }
        "Mar" {
            $psMonth = 3
        }
        "Apr" {
            $psMonth = 4
        }
        "May" {
            $psMonth = 5
        }
        "Jun" {
            $psMonth = 6
        }
        "Jul" {
            $psMonth = 7
        }
        "Aug" {
            $psMonth = 8
        }
        "Sep" {
            $psMonth = 9
        }
        "Oct" {
            $psMonth = 10
        }
        "Nov" {
            $psMonth = 11
        }
        "Dec" {
            $psMonth = 12
        }
    }
    $psDate = "$psMonth" + "/" + $dateparts[2] + "/" + $dateparts[4]
    return $psDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format to parse your string into a `datetime` is **`ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy zzz`**:

```bash
[datetime]::ParseExact(
    'Thu Dec 9 08:52:15 2021 -0500',
    'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy zzz',
    [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).
    ToString('M/d/yyyy')
```

You're correct with `-0400` being the Time Zone.